# Docker Prisma Error P1001: Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, express, prisma

After hours of searchs, I must bow dow and ask you some advices on my problem :

My backend (express + prisma + postgresql) is Dockerized, functionning BUT I can't use `npx prisma` commands from my wsl2 zsh terminal.

Here is my .env

```
# Database settings
NODE_ENV=dev
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=password
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@postgres/chimere?schema=public"
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:17-alpine3.14 as base

WORKDIR /user/src/app
COPY package*.json /user/src/app/
EXPOSE 5000

FROM base as dev
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install -g nodemon && npm install
COPY . /user/src/app/
RUN npx prisma generate
CMD ["nodemon", "src/index.js"]

FROM base as production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm ci
COPY . /user/src/app/
RUN npx prisma generate
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  web:
      build:
        context: ./
        target: dev
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app
        - uploaded-files:/usr/src/app/public/media/files
        - uploaded-pictures:/usr/src/app/public/media/pictures
      command: npm run start:dev
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
      environment:
        NODE_ENV: development
        DEBUG: nodejs-docker-express:*

volumes:
    postgres:
    uploaded-files:
    uploaded-pictures:
```

and Prisma Schema :

```
generator client {
    provider      = "prisma-client-js"
    binaryTargets = ["native", "linux-musl"]
}

datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Like you can see I'm prettry new to Docker and almost everything is an adjusted copypasta from Google (:

How can I get my app to work AND get my commands to work aswell ?

Thanks !

Comment: The database host name will be different if you're running it from within the Compose setup (`postgres`) or from outside a container (`localhost`); you'll need different environment-variable settings to describe the different environments.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
Could you please elaborate or give me an example, I'm a bit lost with Docker :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing the same issue but it was on a `mysql` container. Basically I was having a problem with my `DATABASE_URL` in my `.env` file. It was looking something like this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@localhost:3306/project_name"
```

The problem was that `localhost`. Apparently, when running inside a container, instead of the `localhost`, it uses the **container's name**. I changed my docker compose to specify the container's name:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Notice the `container_name` property. After that, I changed my `.env` to:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@mysql:3306/project_name"
```

I would suggest you to try something similar. Maybe something along these lines:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

And for your `.env` you can leave the way it is now unless you chose a different container's name, then you would subsitute with the name you chose inside the curly braces (remember to remove the curly braces):

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@{container_name}/chimere?schema=public"
```

Check this GitHub issue for more information as well:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1385

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution! Would never thought that container name is going to be used/replaced in connection string

Comment: damn weird this thing, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You need to act from inside the container.

First, create an interactive shell in the container using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#run-docker-exec-on-a-running-container):

```bash
docker exec -it <name of your containter> sh
```

*Note:* the `-i` flag keeps input open to the container, and the `-t` flag creates a pseudo-terminal that the shell can attach to.

Then, once inside the container, execute the commands you need:

```bash
npx prisma migrate dev --name <name of your migration>
```

Comment: Would this be run in the dockerfile i.e. a line `npx prisma migrate dev`? I have a make sure your database is running issue, although my container is up and generate has been run... is it that i would also need to migrate (in the container).