# Docker/Prisma - Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3310`

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, prisma

#### .dev.env

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3310/masterapp_mysql_db_dev?schema=public`

#### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  masterapp-dev-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: masterapp_db
    ports:
    - 3310:3310 
    expose:
      - 3310
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: masterapp_mysql_db_dev
      MYSQL_USER: test_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test_pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%' 
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3310
  server-dev:
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - /server/home/node/server
    env_file:
      - ./server/src/config/envConfig/.dev.env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - masterapp-dev-db
    depends_on:
      - masterapp-dev-db
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:19-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run migrate:mysql:dev

RUN npx prisma generate

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

#### package.json

```
"migrate:mysql:dev": "dotenv -e ./src/config/envConfig/.dev.env -- npx prisma migrate dev --name migrate-msql",
    "db:dev:rm": "docker compose rm masterapp-dev-db -s -f -v",
    "db:dev:up": "docker compose up masterapp-dev-db -d",
    "db:dev:restart": "npm run db:dev:rm && npm run db:dev:up && sleep 1 && npm run migrate:mysql:dev",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --files --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts"
```

First i run `docker compose up masterapp-dev-db -d` which spins up the container for my mysql database. At this point the database i working properly and can be reached on localhost with the environment credentials listed in docker-compose file.

Then I ran `docker compose up server-dev -d`  which gets me the above mentioned error.

I've tried changing localhost to the name of the service (**masterapp-dev-db**) , to the name of the container (**masterapp_db**), to the IP of the container (**172.19.0.2**) and stil got the same error.

Comment: Here's a related Stack Overflow Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663204/docker-prisma-error-p1001-cant-reach-database-server-at-postgres5432
Can you have a look at it and see if you get the same error?