# Google Cloud Build keeps on giving me 'Can't reach database server at'

Tags: database-migration, prisma, google-cloud-build

So I have been at this for days now almost and it is driving me crazy. Based on other posts, I have set up the following cloudbuild.yaml :

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - -t
      - gcr.io/${INSTANCE_NAME}
      - .
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - gcr.io/${INSTANCE_NAME}
  - name: 'gcr.io/${INSTANCE_NAME}'
    entrypoint: sh
    env:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/DATABASE?host=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
        chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
        ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:5432 & sleep 3
        npx prisma migrate deploy
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - run
      - deploy
      - backend
      - --image
      - gcr.io/${INSTANCE_NAME}
      - --region
      - europe-west1
images:
  - gcr.io/${INSTANCE_NAME}
```

When running this, I am greeted by:

```
Step #2: 2023/02/05 13:00:49 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for CONNECTION_NAME
Step #2: 2023/02/05 13:00:49 Ready for new connections
Step #2: 2023/02/05 13:00:49 Generated RSA key in 118.117245ms
Step #2: npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: prisma@4.9.0
Step #2: Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Step #2: Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "develop", schema "public" at "localhost"
Step #2: 
Step #2: Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME`:`5432`
Step #2: 
Step #2: Please make sure your database server is running at `/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME`:`5432`.
```

So even with using the database url hardcoded and with the Cloud SQL proxy working, i am STILL getting this error. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a public IP on your database?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database through an IDE?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue? I'm experiencing exactly same problem. Also using prisma and cloudbuild

Comment: Having the same problem and can't find an answer anywhere why does google make it so difficult to talk to each others products it's maddening I'm ready to abandon it all together

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `container-name` in `.env` file and change it to `postgres` as it would replace name in connection string as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71776281/18265570)

Or try the following format if you don’t want to hardcode IP address

```
DB_USER=dbuser
DB_PASS=dbpass
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=/cloudsql/gcp-project-id:europe-west3:db-instance-name
DATABASE_URL=postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_BASE}?host=${CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}
```

If you have public IP try [connecting by unix socket](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-build#connect_to)